# Proxy Check with wGET?

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd, wget

How do check proxy with wget?

proxylist.txt

```
41.230.30.24:3128
182.253.32.175:3128
77.65.19.35:3128
176.192.42.230:80
...
```

How can I test the proxy list in order.

Example:

> wget http://www.google.com -U Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 -P "" --cookies=off --no-http-keep-alive -e use_proxy=yes --max-redirect 0 -t 1 --timeout=5 -e http_proxy=41.230.30.24:3128
>
> wget http://www.google.com -U Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 -P "" --cookies=off --no-http-keep-alive -e use_proxy=yes --max-redirect 0 -t 1 --timeout=5 -e http_proxy=182.253.32.175:3128

etc..

How can I do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in (proxylist.txt) do wget http://www.google.com -U Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0 -P "" --cookies=off --no-http-keep-alive -e use_proxy=yes --max-redirect 0 -t 1 --timeout=5 -e http_proxy=%%a
```